# How to create 2 class instances injected with different implementation of class's dependencies (via guice)?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have an interface named "Consumer".

The implementation looks as follows:

```
public class ConsumerImpl  implements Consumer {
  DBManager  m_dbm ;
  @Inject
  public ConsumerImpl  (DBManager dbm) {
    m_dbm = sdbm;       
  }
```

}

I need to have 2 instances of the consumerImpl class but with different implementation of the DBManager being injected. How can I configure this via guice?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions and search for "How do I build two similar but slightly different trees of objects?"

Comment: thanks, but i saw this post and i don't think it answers my question

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```java
public class GuiceDependencyExample {

  static class DBManager {}
  static class DBManagerVendor1 extends DBManager {}
  static class DBManagerVendor2 extends DBManager {}
  static interface Consumer {
    DBManager getDbManager();
  }

  static @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @BindingAnnotation @interface DBManager1 {}
  static @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @BindingAnnotation @interface DBManager2 {}

  static class ConsumerImpl  implements Consumer {
    DBManager  m_dbm;
    @Inject
    public ConsumerImpl  (DBManager dbm) { m_dbm = dbm; }

    public DBManager getDbManager() { return m_dbm; }
  }

  static abstract class ConsumerModule extends PrivateModule {
    private final Class<? extends Annotation> annotation;

    ConsumerModule(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
      this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Consumer.class).annotatedWith(annotation).to(ConsumerImpl.class);
      expose(Consumer.class).annotatedWith(annotation);
      bindDbManager();
    }

    abstract void bindDbManager();
  }

  static class Client {
    @DBManager1
    @Inject
    Consumer consumer1;

    @DBManager2
    @Inject
    Consumer consumer2;
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(
        new ConsumerModule(DBManager1.class) {
          @Override void bindDbManager() {
            bind(DBManager.class).toInstance(new DBManagerVendor1());
          }
        },
        new ConsumerModule(DBManager2.class) {
          @Override void bindDbManager() {
            bind(DBManager.class).toInstance(new DBManagerVendor2());
          }
        });
    Client client = i.getInstance(Client.class);
    assertTrue(client.consumer1.getDbManager() instanceof DBManagerVendor1);
    assertTrue(client.consumer2.getDbManager() instanceof DBManagerVendor2);
  }
```

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that somewhere in the code I need explicitly request for Consumer with DBManager1 or DBManager2 dependency (which are mapped to the real class). So this kind of misses the point of just having configuration module somewhere and not knowing the real type and dependencies in the code. Also this is part of a large system and I can't have 2 Injectors.

Comment: How else is your client going to know which type of `Consumer` to get if you don't tell it? And why would you need a second injector? In this example you would just add those private modules to your existing injector...